# Load an module in an rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following test...

## spec/features/users/sign_in_spec.rb

```
require "rails_helper"
feature "User sign in" do
    extend SubdomainHelpers
    let!(:account) { FactoryGirl.create(:account) }
    let(:sign_in_url) { "http://#{account.subdomain}.example.com/sign_in" }
    let(:root_url) { "http://#{account.subdomain}.example.com/" }
    within_account_subdomain do
        scenario "signs in as an account owner successfully" do
            visit root_url
            expect(page.current_url).to eq(sign_in_url)
            fill_in "Email", :with => account.owner.email
            fill_in "Password", :with => "password"
            click_button "Sign in"
            expect(page).to have_content("You are now signed in.")
            expect(page.current_url).to eq(root_url)
        end
    end
end
```

Note the 3rd line `extend SubdomainHelpers` which I am trying to load from...

## spec/support/subdomain_helpers.rb

```
module SubdomainHelpers
    def within_account_subdomain
        let(:subdomain_url) { "http://#{account.subdomain}.example.com" }
        before { Capybara.default_host = subdomain_url }
        after { Capybara.default_host = "http://www.example.com" }
        yield
    end
end
```

When I run the text I get the error `uninitialized constant SubdomainHelpers (NameError)` How do I call the SubdomainHelpers module from the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `require 'support/subdomain_helpers'` in your rails_helper or the sign_in_spec file.

Files in the `spec/support` subdirectory are automagically loaded into `LOAD_PATH` by rspec, but they're not required.

Comment: For posterity, I need both the `extend SubdomainHelpers` and the require 'support/subdomain_helpers' in the sign_in_spec.rb for the test to run.